# Python : String Manipulation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column which has entry like :
`'TURBINE, STEAM ; MAKE: ABB ; MODEL: CF-4GSS ; RATING: OUT PUT 1175 BHP ; SPEED: 2975 MIN -1'`

There is some modifications I need to do after reading this into python. String MUST be of the form :
`ITEM : TURBINE ; COMBUSTION : STEAM ; MAKE : XYZ ; MODEL : XYZ`  and so on.

How can I format it so that the column is of the specified format ?
(Also since im reading this with pandas i think this column will be a series object)

Comment: So what exactly do you need to do? Manipulate a plain Python string or operate with pandas? If it is operations on plain Python strings: do you mean that you only need to add ITEM and then COMBUSTION to the first two entries? Besides, the title of your question is to vague.

Comment: I have a large data frame with dirty data of the form ```TURBINE, STEAM ; MAKE: ABB ; MODEL: CF-4GSS ; RATING: OUT PUT 1175 BHP ; SPEED: 2975 MIN -1``` as you can see, its like a key-value pair my problem is that all values are present in the data but some key names are not. it should be like ```ITEM : Turbine; COMBUSTION : Steam; MAKE : abc ; MODEL : xyz```

Comment: Sorry, to me your posing of the problem is still not sufficient. Is it that always those two first keys that are missing? Or can it be others too? I asked it already, you replied "some are missing". If you were to describe in words the operation you need implemented in Python, what would it be?

Comment: Hey, no im a newbie its not your fault let me pose my problem directly. i have a dataset that contains industrial equipment details in one column extracted from some tool. the column has data in this form :                                                                       
```'TURBINE, STEAM ; MAKE: ABB ; MODEL: CF-4GSS ; RATING: OUT PUT 1175 BHP ; SPEED: 2975 MIN -1'```. As you may notice in THIS particular scenario "turbine" and "steam" are missing their key which would be "item:" and "combustion:" for the first 2 in THIS particular case.

Comment: I want to generalize this column in this format : ```item : xyz; combustion : xyz; make:xyz; model : xyz``` and so on the keys that i have mentioned must always be present, but they are not in this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .split method on your original string:

`new_string = original_string.split()`

Which would give you a list of separate objects for each category in your string like this,  `['TURBINE,', 'STEAM', ';', 'MAKE:', 'ABB', ';', 'MODEL:', 'CF-4GSS', ';', 'RATING:', 'OUT', 'PUT', '1175', 'BHP', ';', 'SPEED:', '2975', 'MIN', '-1']`

Then start a new string for your item `final_string = "ITEM :"`

Then concatenate individual items from your list using indexing, `final_string += new_string[0]`

This would give you `final_string == "ITEM : TURBINE"`. For a different item to add to your string you simply use a different index position from 0. Remember that python indexes from 0 onwards, and each individual item in the list is considered an object so the semi colons would be considered an individual object and you'd need to count them in your indexing. You will also want to add punctuation while you're concatenating.

You could remove all the semi colons from the string by using those to split the original string by inserting it into the .split method `original_string.split(';')`, but that would split the items only when it reaches semi colons, which would give you this, `['TURBINE, STEAM ', ' MAKE: ABB ', ' MODEL: CF-4GSS ', ' RATING: OUT PUT 1175 BHP ', ' SPEED: 2975 MIN -1']`

Comment: only problem is its not a string, its a series object

Comment: Ah sorry. I'm not familiar with those.